# InvokeLater() - will just once be enough?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

I use the recommended code to start my interactive program, which uses Swing.  :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
          } } ) };
```

It creates a JFrame, call it "Foo", and ends when the user closes that window (by using the OS' Close- Window X icon or another OS way to close the app)

I want to display another window, "Bar", get user input, close that window with my own Swing calls, and then display the "Foo" window.

I could reuse the same JFrame for Foo and Bar, and just clear it out in-between. But I prefer to make each of them more independent in their design. So, an ActionListener in Foo would need to close Foo's frame, and call the code that displays Bar.

Do I need to use InvokeLater() to call the code that displays Bar? To get more design independence, should my main() be starting and synchronizing two threads?

Answer (score 2):

User triggered action listener code is executed in the EDT, so you do not need to wrap it again. That said, it may well be that using `CardLayout` would be more appropriate than multiple frames.

Comment: TYVM. In what way is CardLayout better? (i have never used it or read about it.)

Comment: in general users don't want multiple windows, you use just one frame

Comment: @ElHombre55 It provides an easy way to switch window (or any other component) contents. Essentially a cleaner way to reuse the same frame. The layout of the contents can still be designed independently. CardLayout just gives a nice way to select the displayed component tree.

Comment: @nachokk agreed. My UI is that only the menu displays; interactions; only the subject displays, in the same place; interactions.

Answer (score 2):

> I could reuse the same JFrame for Foo and Bar, and just clear it out
>   in-between. But I prefer to make each of them more independent in
>   their design. So, an ActionListener in Foo would need to close Foo's
>   frame, and call the code that displays Bar.
>
> Do I need to use InvokeLater() to call the code that displays Bar? To
>   get more design independence, I am unclear on the operation of the
>   EDT.

- you would use `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` wrapped into `invokeLater` in all cases for

  1. for new `Top-Level Container` - alyways
  2. for container created but never dispayed - always
  3. for container once visible, then hidden and again visible on the screen - always
  4. doesn't matter if is invoked from Swing Listener (by default on EDT) or not
- to my point 3rd. to avoiding any unwanted `Graphics` lacks in the case that you reused `Top-Level Container` (is specifics, very short moment, but could be visible, but not, never annoying)

  - old value is visible, then immediatelly refreshed to current
  - old `JComponent` is visible, then immediatelly refreshed with current `JComponents`
  - `relayout`/ `pack()` , the same issue as a.m.
- `invokeLater` to delay (in most casses with success) this event to the end of `EDT`
- [see my view translated to the code demonstration about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253888/714968)