# How to clear JTextField text after parent component is set `setVisible(false)`?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, componentlistener

I have added `ComponentListener` to `JTextField` parent like this:

```
parent.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        setText("");
    }
});
```

So after parent becomes invisible, `textField` text is set to "". Everything works, but the problem is when I set parent to visible - for some milliseconds previous text of `textField` is displayed, and then field becomes empty. So it's not very nice..

Comment: [common issue JComponents must be reseted or replaced before its container is hidden, see and to test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18253888/714968)

Comment: Hmm.., so no good use of `ComponentListener` in this situation. So now I manually set `textField.setText(null);` for every component in my dialog window before it's set to invisible.

Comment: have to calculating that some, espacially low level listeners can be asynchronous, there container loose Focus, Focus is one of most ....

Comment: out of the record textField.setText(null); != JDialod.revalidate() & JDialog.repaint(), everything its about repaint()

Comment: Yes, I had also to do `textField.repaint();` - it is not enough just to clear the text before setting it's parent to invisible.

Comment: I noticed some problems again.. But found the solution -  below is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before setting the parent to invisible, `textField` field is set `textField.setText(null);` (no need to repaint), then the problem is with focus - it must be set to some initial component like `panel.requestFocusInWindow();`. But the focus is not always set right in time. So `Timer` class solved the problem:

```
textField.setText(null);
panel.requestFocusInWindow();

final int timeout = 5;
        Timer timer = new Timer(timeout, new ActionListener() {
            int a = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (panel.isFocusOwner() || a > 500) {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setVisible(false);
                        }
                    });
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                }
                a += timeout;
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
```

Now Dialog window (parent) if `setVisible(true);` shows as newly created - without blinking textFields and focused right. Finally.. :)

Comment: right it could be, then didn't you thinking about animation ---> fade out durrng one second/half of second, because how much event will be executed during this short period, my question whats Java (target) version???

Comment: Java version is  1.7.0_25-b16. Yes, fade out is a good idea, but in this particular design I simply do not want to do it. But on my custom popup menu - menu items on mouse entered/exited behave so - very nice result.

Comment: I see that (.Net, C++) by replacing form with an image simulating the form, and thenimage is fade out, illusion, illusion, nobody can catch that